# Using WPFPerf to profile a WPF 4.0 application doesn't show me any information

Tags: wpf, profiling

I am trying to use WPFPerf to profile a WPF 4.0 application (I have the latest WPFPerf that should work on WPF 4.0 aps). I start the tool Visual Profiler from WPFPerf, I start my aplication, but after that nothing happens and the element tree from the Visual Profiler is empty. No other error message is shown. Can anyone tell me what am I not doint right?

As an additional information, when I try to analize my .exe assembly or any other assembly from my application, I get a BadFormatException saying that the assembly was build with a newer version of .NET. From the download page http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=191420
I see that this version of WPFPerf should be ok for my app

Comment: Same issue here. This http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wptk_v4/thread/c7c747b4-2314-4c6e-8a31-201b1f010792 didn't help.

Answer (score 7):

**TimeZone patch to WPF Performance Profiling Tools for WPF 4 is now available**
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jgoldb/archive/2010/08/24/timezone-patch-to-wpf-performance-profiling-tools-for-wpf-4-is-now-available.aspx

Comment: I tried this patch but I get the error:
"The upgrade patch cannot be installed by the Windows Installer service because the program to be upgraded may be missing, or the upgrade patch may update a different version of the program. Verify that the program to be upgraded exists on your computer and that you have the correct upgrade patch."

Answer (score 3):

First check to see if its working even with a small blank WPF application. If it is not working with a blank WPF app, then it likely is the patch already mentioned: [TimeZone patch to WPF Performance Profiling Tools for WPF 4 is now available](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jgoldb/archive/2010/08/24/timezone-patch-to-wpf-performance-profiling-tools-for-wpf-4-is-now-available.aspx)

However, in my case that wasn't the issue. Visual Profiler has a bug that causes it not to display the Element tree if it doesn't like some of the characters in its main window title bar.

Through hours of trial and error, I was able to trace the root cause of why it would not work on our application even though it would on a blank WPF application. The reason is that our application has a special character in the title bar text (trademark). If we eliminate the special character from the main window title, the element tree shows fine when the visual profiler is attached. I was able to reproduce this issue in the simple blank WPF application too simply by putting the following property on the main window:

```
<Window ..... Title="Test Application™" >
```

Looks like a bug in Visual Profiler that somehow is triggered by special characters. I didn't test for other special characters, but likely it isn't just this one.

So the workaround is to remove the special character while you are profiling until they fix this.